# Populating TableView with retrieved data from Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I've tried to retrieve data and set it into a tableview; I haven't really succeeded on this.

I want to fetch image and text into the tableView from firebase;

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var homePageTableView: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var imageFiles = [Data]()
    var price = [String]()
    var refHandle:UInt!






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()



        fetchUsers()

func fetchUsers() {

        refHandle = ref.child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (<#DataSnapshot#>) in
            if let retrivedData = DataSnapshot.value(String : AnyObject) {
              ??? 
            }
        })
```

I'm aware of this is unfinished but I have no clue of how to continue from this point. How do I set it to the table??? and how Do I retrieve the data correctly.
Can't find any documentation about this with the newest update firebase SDK and swift 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to feed the retrieved data into model objects and supply to the table view.

This is how modal objects looks like:

```
    class Person {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    }
}
```

Now you have to feed the `JSON` data you got from firebase to this model objects. Once your model object is ready, you have to load the tableview. Tableview has `data source` methods. Use them to show how to populate data in tableview.

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return modelObjectsArray.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell")!
            let modelObject = self.modelObjectsArray[indexPath.row] as! Person
            cell.textLabel?.text = modelObject.firstname
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: So how would this be used in my situation? by retrieving firebase data and set it into tableView... the Firebase way..

Comment: You have retrivedData. Now make a model object class and assign data to it. After assigning it reload tableview

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.codementor.io/brettr/two-basic-ways-to-populate-your-uitableview-du107rsyx

Comment: But there is no need for a model class? I know it will be more readable and prettier, but there is only a list of few data im going to have..... But this is not the issue, I get that part of setting and populate the data into the tableView, but now how to do it with fireBase? the documentation hasn't been update yet you see...